# AFURLSessionManager downloadTaskWithRequest cancels immediately

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I'm using the exact sample code from [the AFNetworking README](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#creating-a-download-task) to download a file, but the request is immediately cancelled:

`File downloaded to: (null) with response = (null) and error = Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled"`

I thought another request might be canceling this one out in my larger application, so I created a new sample project with just one button that just does this download. So I know that isn't the case.

Googling for a solution only returned information about how to voluntarily cancel an existing request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

It is a problem about redirections. Happens with 302 and 301 redirections.

I resolve the problem setting on the AFURLSessionManager object this block:

```
[manager     setSessionDidReceiveAuthenticationChallengeBlock:^NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition (NSURLSession *session, NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *challenge, NSURLCredential * __autoreleasing *credential) {
return NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling;
}];
```

I found the solution here: [AFNetworking 2.0: NSURLSessionDownloadTask is cancelled when received 302 to AWS S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179344/afnetworking-2-0-nsurlsessiondownloadtask-is-cancelled-when-received-302-to-aws/19260698#19260698)

Answer (score 0):

The server was responding with a 302 and the request was canceling itself. I had no way of knowing that unfortunately until I did a curl on the command line.