# AFNetworking 2.0: NSURLSessionDownloadTask is cancelled when received 302 to AWS S3

Tags: https, amazon-s3, afnetworking-2

I'm using a simple example from the README file (from AFNetworking 2.0 page) to download an image. All works fine for the images served directly from my web-sever. 
But for those located on the S3 the web-server returns 302 Redirect the following error:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled"
```

When I try to download the image (using the same code) directly from the S3 (omitting the redirection) I receive the same error.

I've checked the availability of the actual image with wget. The image is publicly available (https://youguide.s3.amazonaws.com/icons/user_96x96.png).

Anyone experience the similar problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was having the same problem with S3 and seem to have resolved it. AFNetworking was returning a value in the authentication challenge handling logic that was canceling the request.

By telling the `AFURLSessionManager` how to handle authentication challenges I've fixed the problem.

```
[manager setSessionDidReceiveAuthenticationChallengeBlock:^NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition (NSURLSession *session, NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *challenge, NSURLCredential * __autoreleasing *credential) {
    return NSURLSessionAuthChallengePerformDefaultHandling;
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. What about cases with AFHTTPRequestOperationManager instead of SessionManager?

Comment: Upgrade your `AFNetworking` to 2.0.1 and the bug should be fixed for you. There was a commit yesterday that fixes this problem across the board since it was done in `AFURLSessionManager` which the HTTP counterpart subclasses. Here's the related GitHub issue thread: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1431#issuecomment-25937811.

Comment: i get the same error with S3 image file with afn 3 how can i solve?